# Voting API for comments with backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js

I have just started experimenting with backbone.js and have hit a roadblock while designing my very first front-end module with it. Here's what I have:

I followed the basic todos tutorial and created a commenting system upon my custom REST API. All good there.

I have a vote up or vote down button for each comment, just like SO. I want to call the REST API which is at

```
POST /api/comments/vote/:id
```

A parameter "direction" (up or down) is also passed.

In my comments view I have a function that calls another function it the comments model like this:

```
vote_up: function() {
    this.model.voteUp();
    return false;
}
```

the function in model:

```
voteUp: function() {
    var up_votes = this.get('up_votes') - 0;
    up_votes++;
    this.save({up_votes: up_votes});
}
```

I am pretty sure I don't need `this.save` here which actually calls the comments API and the sends all the parameters as POST.

I am not sure how to do this in a backbonejs-way (I am looking for something standard).

Comment: What do you mean? I need to call `POST /api/comments/vote/:id` from inside `voteUp`. How do I do that?

Comment: Ah, I see. I've left a proposal below.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a manual `$.ajax` call to `/api/comments/vote/:id` and tell it if you have an upvote or downvote. Then `/api/comments/vote/:id` would send an atomic increment or decrement into the database, read out the new value, and send that back. Then the success handler for your `$.ajax` can do a `set` to update the client-side value.

Your `voteUp` implementation is subject to some obvious timing problems: what happens if you have 6 upvotes in your JavaScript, then 11 other people upvote, and your `voteUp` tries to tell the server that a new upvote has occurred so there should be 7 upvotes? You shouldn't try to maintain counters like this, not even in server-side code.

I guess I'm trying to say that there isn't really a Backboney way to do this, there is a correct way and all sorts of incorrect ways. Do it the correct way and declare, by fiat, that that is the Backboney way.

Comment: The API call will only tell the server to increment or decrement, and not to increment to a certain value (like you mentioned 7 in your example). And one of the return values would include the latest vote count, too, which I can use to update the model and the view.

Comment: So you don't need a `save` call at all, just a simple `$.ajax` call that triggers a `set` to update the counter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard way would be to take advantage of Backbone's urlRoot property.

```
var Vote = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot : '/api/comments/vote'});

// ....in comments view:

vote_up: function() {
    // send HTTP Post '/api/comments/vote/' -- server will create ID
    new Vote({direction: 1}).save()
    return false;
}
```

If you need the Id right away, or to otherwise react to the successful insert, you can pass a `success` callback to `save`.

See: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save